# liquibase is not able execute changeset in DB

Tags: java, liquibase, changeset, database-versioning

I could not figured out why non of the change-set is getting executed and reflected in DB.

I have referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55483210/liquibase-doesnt-excecute-changesets) as well,it has same issue unfortunately there is not answer on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55483210/liquibase-doesnt-excecute-changesets) .

In summary no changesets has been executed and my DB has no Tables (except DATABASCHANGELOG) in it.

[image]

Please refer below code.

Class "**DataVersioningController.java**" has main method and it calls the "liquiebaseRun()" method.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws LiquibaseException, SQLException {
       new DataVersioningController().liquiebaseRun();

    }

    public void  liquiebaseRun() throws SQLException, LiquibaseException {

       JdbcConnection jdbcConnection = new JdbcConnection(DataVersioningController.getConnection());
       DatabaseChangeLog dbChangeLog = new DatabaseChangeLog("D:\\ChangeSet.xml");
       Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(jdbcConnection);

       ClassLoaderResourceAccessor classLoaderAccessor = new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor();

       CommandLineResourceAccessor clAccessor = new CommandLineResourceAccessor(getClass().getClassLoader());

        CompositeResourceAccessor ref = new CompositeResourceAccessor(new ResourceAccessor[] { clAccessor, classLoaderAccessor });
       database.setDefaultSchemaName("test");
       database.setLiquibaseSchemaName("test");
       Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase(dbChangeLog, ref, database);
       liquibase.update(new Contexts("test"), new LabelExpression());

       System.out.println("Completed ");
  }
```

**ChangeSet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

    <changeSet author="admin" id="1" context="test">
        <createTable tableName="person">
            <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="INT">
                <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="VARCHAR(255)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="address" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
        </createTable>

    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call liquibase manualy.
If you are using SpringBoot and Maven then add that dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.liquibase/liquibase-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

and that property to your application.properties:

```
spring.liquibase.change-log=//path to your changeset
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where changeset wasn't getting applied as I was using `SpringLiquibase` with `schema per tenant`.

I needed to set `liquibase.setLabelFilter(schemaName)` to resolve the change log caching issue.